# Oracle APEX: How can i take the value from a column in my page

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page and i want to show a success message using the value from a column of this page!
How can i do this?

I try with

apex.message.showPageSuccess(“The Client” + apex.column  “LAST_NAME”.getValue());

but it has only apex.item not column...

Comment: In what sense does a column have "the" value? By definition a column may have multiple values, one for each row.

Comment: I want to show the specific value of this column when the save button is pressed

Comment: *by definition, a column may have multiple values*